# GraphQL graph.cool user query not working with Auth0 token

Tags: reactjs, graphql, auth0, graphcool

Despite using a theoretically working authentication token, the userQuery request from UserProvider returns a null `user` and networkStatus of 7, indicating that it is done loading and that there is no "error," despite the user being null.

```
class UserProvider extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.data.user) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("userId", this.props.data.user.id)
    }

    if (this.props.data.loading) {
      return <div>Loading</div>
    }

    return this.props.children(this.props.data.user)
  }
}

const userQuery = gql`
  query {
    user {
      id
    }
  }
`

export default graphql(userQuery, {
  options: { fetchPolicy: "network-only" },
})(UserProvider)
```

I am setting up the network interface with this code.

```
const wsClient = new SubscriptionClient(
  `wss://subscriptions.graph.cool/v1/redacted`,
  {
    reconnect: true,
  }
)

const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: "https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/redacted",
})

const networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions = addGraphQLSubscriptions(
  networkInterface,
  wsClient
)

networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions.use([
  {
    applyMiddleware(req, next) {
      if (!req.options.headers) {
        req.options.headers = {}
      }

      console.log("applying middleware")

      // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
      if (localStorage.getItem("auth0IdToken")) {
        console.log("apply header", localStorage.getItem("auth0IdToken"))
        req.options.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(
          "auth0IdToken"
        )}`
      }

      next()
    },
  },
])

let client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: networkInterfaceWithSubscriptions,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `user` query will return `null` in your situation, when there is no `User` node in your Graphcool project where `auth0UserId` corresponds with the Auth0 id embedded in the JWT.

Please paste your token to https://jwt.io/ and check if a user exists with an id that is printed there. The Auth0 id starts with the auth provider, for example `google-oauth2|<google id>` for Google.